# Angular: Pass ng-repeat Item Into Directive

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do you pass an entire `ng-repeat` object into a directive (or how to you set a directive's scope to an `ng-repeat` item)?

I'm new to angular and having a difficult time figuring this out.

I have a controller which renders the following just fine:

```
<div class="img-wrap" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <p>{{image.title}}</p>
    <img ng-src="{{image.thumbUrl}}" />
</div>
```

What i would like to do is turn the inside into a directive and pass the `image` obj into the directive. Here's what i have that does NOT work:

I change the html to:

```
<div class="img-wrap" ng-repeat="image in images">
  <image />
</div>
```

And then i have this directive:

```
angular.module('openart')
.factory('image',  function () {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        controller:['$scope',function($scope){

        }],
        template:'<p>{{title}}</p><img ng-src="{{thumbUrl}}" />',
        link:function(scope,el,attrs){

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: factory is not a directive as I know )

Comment: @hawk haha this is why i hate/love/hate programming. nice catch thx!

Answer (score 9):

You have to provide the image object to your directive somehow.
For that you need to set it in scope of your directive, something like that:

```
scope: {image:"="}
```

Heres a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaroslavya/8YEkh/)

Comment: Can you modify somehow the image on the scope but inside the nested controller?? controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
            console.log($scope);
        }]